# Emacs automode for R markdown files

Tags: r, emacs, r-markdown, spacemacs

I am trying to automatically associate R markdown files (`.Rmd` and `.rmd`) with markdown-mode in spacemacs, also enabling markdown preview.

I have tried a number of variations, none of which worked. here is one of the latest:

```
   (use-package markdown-mode
    :ensure t
    :commands (markdown-mode gfm-mode)
    :mode (("README\\.md\\'" . gfm-mode)
           ("\\.md\\'" . markdown-mode)
           ("\\.rmd\\'" . markdown-mode)
           ("\\.Rmd\\'" . markdown-mode)
           ("\\.markdown\\'" . markdown-mode))
    :init (setq markdown-command "multimarkdown"))
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Seems fine. Did you restart emacs or at least reload `.spacemacs`?

Comment: yup, both actually

Comment: @RicardoPietrobon, did you solve this issue?

Comment: @EricFail nope, ended up moving to nvim to use nvim-r